# a variety-seeking woman

Tags: idiom-requests

In my language, there is an adjective that is ascribed to men and women who want to have many different sexual partners. In other words, they seek to have a great degree of variety in terms of their sex partners. This adjective literally translates to "variety seeking".

Example: She is a variety seeking woman. She has slept with many different men.

Is there a word, adjective, expression or anything in English with the same meaning?

I already know polygamous. But it's a bit scientific!

And what is the opposite? A person who only wants to have one sexual partner?

Answer (score 5):

The word describing a person practising such behaviour is **promiscuous**.

> *promiscuous* adjective
>
> 1: having or involving many sexual partners : not restricted to one
>   sexual partner or few sexual partners

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promiscuous)]

............

> - *I suppose I was quite promiscuous in my youth.*
> - *It's a fallacy that gay men are more promiscuous than heterosexuals.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/promiscuous), which also adds the caveat 'of a person'; though this is the major usage, broadenings are quite common.]

..............................

A nearish-antonym would be 'happily married', though it's not an exact opposite.

One sense of **monogamous**, in fact the one (as a noun) [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monogamy)
 lists first (most common), is a near-antonym, but the base meaning is 'the practice/law of marriage to no more than one partner at any given time':

> *monogamy*
>
> 1a: the state or practice of having only one sexual partner at a time
>
> - *young couples who practice monogamy*

Comment: How common is it in everyday English?

Comment: It's the usual non-slang term (Slang synonyms are common, eg 'He puts it about a bit', see [Partridge NPD of Slang & ...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mAdUqLrKw4YC&pg=PA1565&lpg=PA1565&dq=%22put+it+about+a+bit%22&source=bl&ots=t3S5cMofCD&sig=ACfU3U0EU-ZbZz1jMZG3T14TNHCSuzVtsw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22put%20it%20about%20a%20bit%22&f=false)); care has to be taken in not using it slanderously, of course.

Comment: It's the usual non-slang term (Slang synonyms are common, eg 'He puts it about a bit', see [Partridge NPD of Slang & ...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mAdUqLrKw4YC&pg=PA1565&lpg=PA1565&dq=%22put+it+about+a+bit%22&source=bl&ots=t3S5cMofCD&sig=ACfU3U0EU-ZbZz1jMZG3T14TNHCSuzVtsw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22put%20it%20about%20a%20bit%22&f=false) / 'He has had more sexual partners than I have had hot dinners'); care has to be taken in not using it slanderously, of course.

Answer (score 2):

How about **playing the field**?

> to hold an interest in a number of people or things, especially to become romantically or sexually involved with a number of partners

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/play-the-field)

This is an informal and fairly neutral way to put it.

The opposite would be **committed**:

> Definition of committed relationship: a serious and lasting romantic relationship with someone

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/committed%20relationship)

For example, in Taylor Swift’s [The Man](https://genius.com/Taylor-swift-the-man-lyrics):

> They'd say I played the field before
>   I found someone to commit to

Answer (score 2):

Another term is [polyamorous](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/polyamorous):

> Characterized by or involved in the practice of engaging in multiple
>   sexual relationships with the consent of all the people involved.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about a word to describe men and women who want to have many different sexual partners. It might be useful to look at synonyms for voracious appetites.

Such sexual athletes might be avid, insatiable, rapacious, ravenous or gluttonous in their unquenchable pursuits of the opposite yet slower moving sex.